# How to lower video down vertically html

Tags: html, center

I got my website to align horizontally and now I want to bump it down a bit vertically so it's not completely touching the top of the page and looking funky.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm a noob.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SimWorks Performance</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("128.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div.center iframe{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="center">
<iframe width="853" height="505" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m6nOEMQlb3Q?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br><br>
<center>
<h1 style="color:white;">COMING SOON</h1>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into the `position` and `top` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `margin-top` to your body tag.
Here is the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SimWorks Performance</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("128.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top:100px;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Fantasy;
    font-size: 10px;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div.center iframe{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="center">
<iframe width="853" height="505" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m6nOEMQlb3Q?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br><br>
<center>
<h1 style="color:white;">COMING SOON</h1>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

I have edited my answer to solve the problem of fonts. Do not put them in your body tag as it will be applied to all elements. Rather put them in your h1 so it will be applied only to h1 elements.

Comment: Now how do I change the font, do I put that in the body tag if it's just text below the video? Also is it okay to center it, or should I format that in CSS somehow

Comment: @scwbrian center tags are not recommended practice, so if possible use css to center it.

Comment: @scwbrian Use margin:auto in your h1 styling. This will horizontally center it. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using padding as per your requirement

**Left Padding**

```
.body {
      background-color: black;
      background-image: url("128.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
      padding-left:20px;
}
```

**Top Padding**

```
.body {
      background-color: black;
      background-image: url("128.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
      padding-top:20px;
}
```

**Overall Padding**

```
.body {
      background-color: black;
      background-image: url("128.jpg");
      background-repeat: repeat;
      padding:20px;
}
```